# fire .change with keyup and keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which works as long as I use the mouse to select an option from the selectbox, or use keyboard arrow keys to select the option, but when using the keyboard, the change event does not fire until I press enter on the keyboard.

How would I detect a change using the keyboard arrow keys without having to press enter?

```
$('#select_box').change(function() {
    some_function($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: does below answers not satisfactory??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to avoid calling your function multiple times unnecessarily, which will happen if you are not careful with multiple events.  You can avoid this by checking if the value of the field has actually changed before calling it.  One way of doing this, shown below, is to store a property on the field with the previous value and then using that to check if the field's value has changed before calling your function:

```
var previousValuePropertyKey = 'previousValue';

$('#select_box').bind('keyup change', function(event) {
    var previousValue = $(this).prop(previousValuePropertyKey);
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).prop(previousValuePropertyKey, currentValue );

    if(previousValue != currentValue ){
        alert(currentValue);//TODO remove alert
        //Yourfunction(..);
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/6tBVS/)'s a fiddle for an example.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
$('#select_box').bind('keyup change',function() {
    some_function($(this).val());
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/bind)

Comment: [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) are all key events; you can use multiple events with `live`

Comment: No need for live here, to be honest - it's overkill. Just bind on keyup like the other example.

Comment: @diEcho: Don't use live unless you need to. Using live will be slower. Even if you want to implement live functionality you should use delegate for performance.

Comment: @amustill; u r right but i always like to use `live`; this is best practise, works with the  future elements too

Comment: @diEcho: it is definitively not best practice.

Comment: @PeeHaa; thanks for the information; i'll keep in mind.Thanks :)

Comment: If you MUST use something like 'live', use event delegation instead. But if you find yourself using either most of the time then you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select_box').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});

$('#select_box').keyup(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```